# How to restrict columns in angular js custom popup

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have controller like this and I have defined some 10 columns in the popup.

```
app.controller('PopupCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$http', 
'$log','$timeout','$q', '$interval','uiGridConstants', 
'uiGridPinningConstants', 'dataService', function ( $scope, $window, 
$http, $log, $timeout, $q, $interval, uiGridConstants, 
uiGridPinningConstants, dataService) 

$scope.PopupOpt = {};

$scope.bomPopupOpt.columnDefs = [ Assume here I have defined some 10 columns]
```

I need to display only 3 columns for particular type(footwear,appare like this) based on the selection. How can I achieve this? I have tried to reset the columnDefs on selection of particular type.But I am not successful. Please help.

Comment: plwease review your post code and put your html ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much descriptive but below is the way you can limit.

```
if(type==1){
 columnToBeShown = ['a','b','c']
} else if(type==2){
 columnToBeShown = ['a','b','c','d']
} else if(type==3){
 columnToBeShown = ['a','b','c','d','e']
}

$scope.bomPopupOpt.columnDefs = columnToBeShown
```